# Why doesn't the virtualbox settings window show the correct info

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

When in Virtualbox (I tried different versions 5.0.2, 4.3.30, 4.3.28,4.3.26), if I go to the settings page and select an option in the left panel, it shows the configuration page of the option directly above it.

[image: Trying to select the audio settings]

Furthermore, I cannot select the options for Network and everything below... So when I try to change the shared folder settings, I get no title and the options of what the "General" page.

[image]

I checked on Google and the bug tracker of virtual box but searches for "Virtual box settings" do have double meanings...

(Win7 machine with admin rights)

Has anybody experienced this behavior?

Comment: That is certainly strange.  Are you using any software on your machine that might be modifying mouse events?  Does the same thing happen if you try and navigate via the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, also when navigating with the keyboard. Have since installed the dev version 5.0.3... Same issue...